Keyboard Interrupt a Docker container process running inside a subprocess
I'm currently building a system that connects a Docker container into a websocket, where the client can then interact with this container through the websocket. I want to give the client the ability to interrupt the process that's running inside the Docker container using keyboard interrupt.
So far my attempt has been as follows:

.........

pty, tty = pypty.openpty()

async def interact_docker(pty, websocket):
    while True:
        data = os.read(pty, 10240)
        print(data)
            # using python's pty as I/O, everytime client gives an input, 
            # the pty reflects this input and duplicates the input into the output. 
            # ex: command "ls" inputted by client will output "ls\r\n" and the result of "ls".
            # to prevent duplicated output from input, save the length of the input string 
            # and add 2 to account for \r\n. Then, for each output from pty, check the first
            # (len(input) + 2) string, and check if the string ends in \r\n. If it does, it means
            # the output is a duplicate of the input, so emit this duplicate.
        check_duplicate = data[:offset]
        if check_duplicate[(offset - 2):] == "\r\n".encode():
            data = data[offset:]

        try:
            await websocket.send_text(data.decode())
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            print("decoding error")
            await websocket.send_text(data.decode("latin-1"))

container = subprocess.Popen(['docker', 'run', '--name', str(instance.id), '-it', '--rm', '--privileged', '-e', 'DISPLAY', '-v', '/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix', '-v', '/lib/modules:/lib/modules', 'iwaseyusuke/mininet'], stdin=tty, stdout=tty, stderr=tty)

loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: asyncio.run(interact_docker(pty, websocket)))   
    
while True:
    data = await websocket.receive_text()
    if data == "^C":
        print("keyboard interrupt")
        container.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
    correct_inp = process_input(db, instance, data, expected_inp)
    if correct_inp and len(expected_inp) == 0 and not finished_lab:
        message = "\x1b[1;92m \nSelamat! Anda telah menyelesaikan lab ini.\nAnda bisa melanjutkan penggunaan lab atau anda bisa kembali ke menu utama untuk menghentikan pengerjaan lab. \x1b[0m\n\n"
        await websocket.send_text(message)
        user.finished_labs.append(lab)
        db.commit()
    offset = len(data) + 2    
    data = data + "\n"
    os.write(pty, data.encode())

def process_input(db, instance, inp, expected_inp):
    if len(expected_inp) == 0:
        return True
    
    if expected_inp[0] == inp:
        expected_inp.pop(0)
        crud.update_lab_instance_expected_input(db, instance, expected_inp)
        return True

    #TODO: Implement interchangeable order for certain expected inputs
    #TODO: Implement optional input
    #TODO: Implement "or" inputs
    
    return False

Basically what's happening here, is I'm running a Docker container using Python's Subprocess with the command subprocess.popen(). This subprocess is connected with a pty that I've set up using Python's pty. Using this pty, clients can interact with the container's bash to send commands like "ls -al" and get the response of "ls -al" from the container's bash. The issue here, is that with a command like ping that runs indefinitely, the client is basically stuck with ping output because they currently have no way to interrupt ping.
So, to summarize, I want to send interrupt signals into the running process of a docker container bash, which in turn is running inside Python's subprocess.
There's some lines of code being omitted for clearance, but the main idea of the script is there. Currently this attempt using container.send_signal(signal.SIGINT) just kills the container. Sending "^C" to the pty doesn't send a SIGINT into the process inside the container, instead it just sends the literal string.
The full function is as follows:
@router.websocket("/interact")
async def interact_with_instance(websocket: WebSocket, token: Annotated[str | None, Cookie()] = None, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    pty, tty = pypty.openpty()

    await manager.connect(websocket)

    if not token:
        message = "\x1b[1;91mKoneksi gagal!\nPastikan anda sudah memiliki instance untuk mengerjakan suatu lab.\n \x1b[0m \n \n"
        await websocket.send_text(message)
        manager.disconnect(websocket)
        raise WebSocketException(code=status.WS_1008_POLICY_VIOLATION, reason="Unauthorized")
    
    try:
        user_id = utils.read_token(token).get("id")
        instance = crud.get_lab_instance_by_user(db, user_id)
    except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
        message = "\x1b[1;91mKoneksi gagal!\nPastikan anda sudah memiliki instance untuk mengerjakan suatu lab.\n \x1b[0m \n \n"
        await websocket.send_text(message)
        manager.disconnect(websocket)
        raise WebSocketException(code=status.WS_1008_POLICY_VIOLATION, reason="Unauthorized")
    
    if not instance:
        message = "\x1b[1;91mKoneksi gagal!\nPastikan anda sudah memiliki instance untuk mengerjakan suatu lab.\n \x1b[0m \n \n"
        await websocket.send_text(message)
        raise WebSocketException(code=status.WS_1008_POLICY_VIOLATION, reason="Unauthorized")
    
    offset = 0

    async def interact_docker(pty, websocket):
        while True:
            data = os.read(pty, 10240)
            print(data)
                # using python's pty as I/O, everytime client gives an input, 
                # the pty reflects this input and duplicates the input into the output. 
                # ex: command "ls" inputted by client will output "ls\r\n" and the result of "ls".
                # to prevent duplicated output from input, save the length of the input string 
                # and add 2 to account for \r\n. Then, for each output from pty, check the first
                # (len(input) + 2) string, and check if the string ends in \r\n. If it does, it means
                # the output is a duplicate of the input, so emit this duplicate.
            check_duplicate = data[:offset]
            if check_duplicate[(offset - 2):] == "\r\n".encode():
                data = data[offset:]

            try:
                await websocket.send_text(data.decode())
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                print("decoding error")
                await websocket.send_text(data.decode("latin-1"))

    container = subprocess.Popen(['docker', 'run', '--name', str(instance.id), '-it', '--rm', '--privileged', '-e', 'DISPLAY', '-v', '/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix', '-v', '/lib/modules:/lib/modules', 'iwaseyusuke/mininet'], stdin=tty, stdout=tty, stderr=tty)

    lab_id = instance.lab_id
    user_id = instance.user_id
    lab = lab_crud.get_lab(db, lab_id)
    user = auth_crud.get_user(db, user_id)
    expected_inp = instance.expected_input
    finished_lab = lab in user.finished_labs

    instantiated = False

    try:
        while True:
            print("init")
            data = os.read(pty, 10240)                              # docker will initialize and sends a bunch of initialization output, don't send this back to the client
            print(data)
            print(data.decode()[0:6] == "docker")
            if data.decode()[0:6] == "docker":                      # detect if docker run runs into an error that the container name already exists, run the existing container
                container = subprocess.Popen(['docker', 'exec', '-it', str(instance.id), 'bash'], stdin=tty, stdout=tty, stderr=tty)
                instantiated = True
                
            if data.decode()[0:17] == "\x1b[?2004h\x1b]0;root@" and not instantiated:    # detect that initialization has finished, send the output into the websocket
                print("INTO B")
                path = f"temp/{instance.id}.py"
                container_path = f"{instance.id}:/tmp/script.py"
                with open(path, "w+") as f:
                    f.write(lab.script)
                container = subprocess.run(["docker", "cp", path, container_path])
                os.remove(path)
                command = "python3 /tmp/script.py\n"
                os.write(pty, command.encode())
                break

            if data.decode()[0:17] == "\x1b[?2004h\x1b]0;root@" and instantiated:
                print("INTO C")
                command = "python3 /tmp/script.py\n"
                os.write(pty, command.encode())
                break

        data = os.read(pty, 10240)
        print(data)
        await websocket.send_text("\x1b[1;93m")

        while True:
            data = os.read(pty, 10240)
            print(data)

            if data.decode()[0:17] == "\x1b[?2004h\x1b]0;root@" or data.decode()[-9:] == "mininet> ":
                break

            await websocket.send_text(data.decode())
        
        if finished_lab:
            message = "\n\x1b[1;92mSelamat! Anda sudah pernah menyelesaikan lab ini. \nAnda tetap bisa melanjutkan pemakaian lab, tetapi tidak akan ada penilaian lebih lanjut untuk pengerjaan lab ini. \x1b[0m \n"
            await websocket.send_text(message)

        await websocket.send_text("\x1b[0m")
        await websocket.send_text("\n")
        await websocket.send_text(data.decode())

        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: asyncio.run(interact_docker(pty, websocket)))   
         
        while True:
            data = await websocket.receive_text()
            if data == "^C":
                print("keyboard interrupt")
                cmd = f"docker exec {instance.id} kill -INT 1"
                os.write(pty, cmd.encode())
            correct_inp = process_input(db, instance, data, expected_inp)
            if correct_inp and len(expected_inp) == 0 and not finished_lab:
                message = "\x1b[1;92m \nSelamat! Anda telah menyelesaikan lab ini.\nAnda bisa melanjutkan penggunaan lab atau anda bisa kembali ke menu utama untuk menghentikan pengerjaan lab. \x1b[0m\n\n"
                await websocket.send_text(message)
                user.finished_labs.append(lab)
                db.commit()
                # TODO: add lab finished column to lab and user model, and add lab to finished
                # plus save docker log for manual verification
                # TODO: docker logs only logs input of the first window. Subsequent windows are not recorded in docker logs
            offset = len(data) + 2    
            data = data + "\n"
            os.write(pty, data.encode())

    except:
        loop.close()
        manager.disconnect(websocket)
        os.close(pty)

def process_input(db, instance, inp, expected_inp):
    if len(expected_inp) == 0:
        return True
    
    if expected_inp[0] == inp:
        expected_inp.pop(0)
        crud.update_lab_instance_expected_input(db, instance, expected_inp)
        return True

    #TODO: Implement interchangeable order for certain expected inputs
    #TODO: Implement optional input
    #TODO: Implement "or" inputs
    
    return False



what part of your code runs on the docker host ? and what part in the container ?

Every line runs on the host. Basically I'm using the container sort of as a VM, where the client can run anything they want like they're interacting with a Linux CLI. What I want to do is, for example, if the client wants to run a ping command that runs indefinitely, I want the client to have the ability to interrupt with CTRL+C and stop that process. Problem is, the ping command is running in the docker container, which is running inside the python subprocess.

Does it work to literally send the ^c character b'\x03' to the subprocess?  Could you directly use the Docker API here, without involving a subprocess?

It worked! Can't believe it's that simple all this time... Thank you! About the Docker API, the API doesn't offer interactive container execution sadly, which is what I want.

If you somehow have a server running inside the container, send that server a specific message, and add code on the server side to trigger a SIGINT.

If you want to send a signal to a a process inside the container, use docker exec:
docker exec <container_name> kill -INT [pid]

If that process is the main process of your container, it has pid 1:
# don't run this at home ;)
docker exec <container_name> kill -INT 1


I was looking for more details about shells and terminals, I found this answer (on unix.stackexchange.com) which explains quite a bit on how to manage things from bash alone:
trying to make my own shell handle ctrl+c properly

The container is simply running bash, and clients can interact with the container's bash through the websocket. All I need is a way to interrupt whatever process is running inside the container, while the container itself is running using python's subprocess.

can you update your question with an outline of your code for process_input() ?

Sure, but it probably doesn't add much context. It's more or less a function for an autograder.

@FarelMusyaffa: I see you updated the code to try to run docker exec .... A docker exec ... command is not meant to be sent to the tty, it is meant to be executed from the docker host : Popen(["docker", "exec", ...]).wait(). Also: I see you start a python script python3 /tmp/script.py inside your container, is this the long running process you want to interrupt ? If so, you would have to send INT to that process (not to pid 1). Choose a way to get that process' pid.

Yeah I'm not running docker exec on the tty. On the contrary, I'm running docker exec on the docker host using python's subprocess.popen(), and then assigning the I/O of that subprocess to the tty. This way I can interact with the docker container's bash using the subprocess, which pipes the subprocess I/O (in this case the docker container bash) into the tty. I can then write input through the tty, which will write it into the subprocess, which is running a docker container bash, which means that the input that gets written into the subprocess using tty goes into the container bash.

Long running process is arbitrary in this case. A user might want to run a command in the container's bash like ping, or they want to create their own arbitrary script and run it in the container. It can be any process, really. I'm trying to give the client sort of like a bash CLI simulator, so therefore ideally they can do anything they can do on a terminal or CLI like keyboard interruption through interacting with a websocket.

(comment n-2) os.write(pty, f"docker exec {instance.id} kill -INT 1".encode()) we are talking about that line, right ? you tell me that this ends up being executed on the host and not inside the container ?

Oh right I forgot I tried it that way, that's a bit silly on my part lol. So should I use subprocess.run() to run docker exec kill?

yes, and kill -INT 1 would send the signal to "the root process of your container". If you want to send the signal to a pid other than 1, you have to get smart about how to target that pid, or write a signal handler that forwards the signal to the appropriate process.

That's a good idea, but it would take some extra work of targeting the PID like you said. Turns out David Maze's idea of sending \x03 to the tty worked perfectly! Can't believe it's that simple all this time lol. I appreciate your help as well! I would've never thought about your solution and it would've worked too!

oh, I had tested that on my system and couldn't get it to work. All good then !
